$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\exp[-x^{-\gamma}]}{x^d}=0$
Trying to show for $\gamma \in (0,1]$ and some natural number $d$ that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\exp[-x^{-\gamma}]}{x^d}=0$$.
I've tried setting $t=x^{-\gamma}$ and you get for the right side limit
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-t}t(1/t)^{\frac{\gamma-d}{\gamma}} = \lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-t}t^{1-\frac{\gamma-d}{\gamma}} = \lim_{t \to \infty}$$

To show $t^{d/\gamma} / e^t \to 0$, recall that exponential growth is faster than polynomial growth, e.g. see here.

@angryavian perfect! does this also work for the left side limit?

As mentioned in the comments, after your substitution, you get
$$\text{your limit}=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^{\frac{d}{\gamma}}}{e^t}= 0$$
by a well-known result (see the link in the comments for a good reference).
You seem to be confused with right/left limits, but when $x \to 0$, $t \to \infty$, so this is a straightforward consequence of change of variable theorem for limits and you don't need to split the limits into left and right hand side limits.
